# Vertical lines on left side of MacBook Pro screen

Tags: macbook-pro

I've got a 2016 MacBook Pro. Since this morning the left hand side of the screen has an issue. Almost two centimetres are black with an occasional coloured line. I'm guessing this is a hardware issue rather than software (I've tried a restart).

What's my best course of action? I'm fairly adept at computer hardware maintenance, so if it's a simple case of opening it up and jiggling a cable I can do that.

I don't have apple care, but my company would pay for the repair anyway (assuming it's not so high it would be a write off).

[image]

Comment: Most definitely a hardware issue. As to how much it will cost to fix, or if the fix is easy or hard is not really diagnosable remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took it to the genius bar and they said the crack itself was accidental damage so couldn't be fixed under warranty.

However the employee looked for other damage which could be and found that the space bar had been rubbing on the screen causing a little damage, and that could be replaced under warranty so I got the entire repair for free. The total cost would have been £558 plus tax.

I should get it back sometime this weekend. I'm impressed by Apple support this time.